# rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'slug': ALTER TABLE `categories`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Recently I implemented `friendly_id` on two models on my **local** rails application. I created two migrations `add_slug_to_categories` and `add_slug_to_services`. And did rest the steps and got `friendly_id` urls working. Then I pushed the same migrations changes to my production server. And then in production rails console I ran `Category.find_each(&:save)` and `Service.find_each(&:save)` and got it working on the production too.

Then for some testing purpose on my local machine I took the `dump.sql` from the production and and dropped the existing db on my local by running `rake db:drop` and created by `rake db:create` and ran `rake db:migrate`. And then I pushed the `dump.sql` to the local db. Then when I ran `rails s` I got `migrations pending` error. So I went ahead and ran `rake db:migrate` again. Then I got

```
== 20170411073744 AddSlugToCategories: migrating ==============================
-- add_column(:categories, :slug, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'slug': ALTER TABLE `categories` ADD `slug`
```

I tried dropping the db and again creating many times. But I keep getting the same issue. Could somebody please tell how can I fix this?

Comment: Yeah i tried with `rails g migration RemoveSlugFromCategories slug:string` and after that ran `rake db:migrate` again. Got the same error.

Comment: Commands are `ALTER TABLE categories` and `DROP COLUMN slug` ??

Comment: Isn't there a rails way of doing this?

Comment: Do I have to do this every time I import `dump.sql` from production?

Comment: It's working now. But as I asked do I have to do this every time I import `dump.sql` from production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the current issue you need to run `ALTER TABLE categories DROP COLUMN slug;` in `dbconsole`, in the future you first need to import `dump.sql` and then migrate `rake db:migrate`